# Inflate multiples views into a fragment

Tags: android-layout, kotlin, layout-inflater, android-inflate

I was working on my app and i need to make a list of little groups of views like this :

(i couldn't post my image 'cause StackOverflow thing i'm not famous enought)

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqP5a.jpg)

The fragment is shown , and correctly applied but the view group that i'm trying to display doesn't.

I can't find how to make my fragment apprear and make the buttons work (But that's not the point now , so I'll ask the question later)

```
class EditFragment : Fragment() {
lateinit var option : Spinner
lateinit var result : TextView
private lateinit var viewOfLayout: View
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?

): View? {

    viewOfLayout =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_fragment, container, false)

    val mainLayout = viewOfLayout.findViewById(R.id.scrollView1) as ScrollView
    //create a view to inflate the layout_item (the xml with the textView created before)
    val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.sensor_item, mainLayout, false)

    val options = arrayOf("A","V")

    option = view.spinner as Spinner
    result = view.textView7 as TextView
    option.adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(activity,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,options)

return viewOfLayout
}
```

}

Here is the full code : https://pastebin.com/fYyXkupM

(I precise that my fragment is displaying properly)

-> I think my error is comming from there :

```
val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.sensor_item, mainLayout, false)
```

if i replace "mainLayout" by "container" it does works but it's not the fragment's child.

Thank you.

Comment: What error are you getting??

Comment: I see you are inflating the view, but I don't see you are doing anything with it after that, like adding it to `viewOfLayout`

Comment: You probably want to include the view in the layout file rather than in code, please see https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok , even if that's a little specific , i found my answer :

```
val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.sensor_item, container, false)
val insertPoint = viewOfLayout.findViewById(R.id.box_Parent) as LinearLayout
insertPoint.addView(view2, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized option Spinner from viewOfLayout.